# Laravel Route resource does not update when form is posted

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.6 and MySQL. I am going to update the student table using the following controller function:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $students = Student::find($id);
        $students->name = $request->input('name');
        $students->town = $request->input('town');
        $students->save();
 }
```

and the update form action looks like this:

```
<form action="{{route('student.update',$students->id)}}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
```

and my route is define like this:

```
Route::resource('student','StudentController');
```

My problem is, when I click the update button in the form it generates the following error message

> 1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using wrong HTTP method, `update` method on `Route::resource` route requires that request is sent with PUT/PATCH HTTP method.

Since HTTP forms doesn't support PUT/PATCH as method you should spoof HTTP method by using Blade directive `@method('PUT')` inside form.

```
<form action="{{route('student.update',$students->id)}}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}

    {!! @method('PUT') !!}
</form>
```

Comment: now I am using this new form like this `<form action="{{route('student.update',$students->id)}}" method="PUT">` but now no any error but not updated data in to database

Comment: Noo, ``method="POST"`` but use Blade directive inside form to simulate PUT request, see my example above.

Comment: good, Aleksa it should be as `{!! method_field('PUT') !!}`, can you correct it in your answer. because need accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="/admin/manage-banners/{{$id}}" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')

    //rest of your code
    ...

</form>
```

The above code works for me in laravel 9.
`{!! method_field('PUT') !!}` gave me error.

Answer (score 0):

Verify your route by executing the command :

`php artisan route:list`

and do check if your request is either sent with 'PUT or PATCH'

I see you are trying to update **$student**. So instead `$student->save()`

You may do it like this :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
       try
      {
        $input = $request->all();

        $student = Student::where('id',$id)->update($input);

        return $student;

     }catch(QueryException $ex) {
        return ['success'=>false, 'error'=>$ex->getMessage()];
    }
 }
```